# Regex not grabbing all groups, not working in multiline

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have the following regex pattern:

```
pattern = r'''
        (?P<name>.+?)\n
        SKU\s#\s+(?P<sku_hidden>\d+)\n
        Quantity:\s+(?P<quantity>\d+)\n
        Gift\sWrap:\s+(?P<gift_wrap>.+?)\n
        Shipping\sMethod:.+?\n
        Price:.+?\n
        Total:\s+(?P<total_price>\$[\d.]+)
        '''
```

I retrieve them using:

```
re.finditer(pattern, plain, re.M | re.X)
```

Yet using `re.findall` yields the same result.

It should match texts like this:

```
Red Retro Citrus Juicer
SKU # 403109
Quantity: 1
Gift Wrap: No
Shipping Method:Standard
Price: $24.99
Total: $24.99
```

The first thing that is happening is that using `re.M` and `re.X` it doesn't work, but if I put it all in one line it does. The other thing is that when it does work only the first group is caught and the rest ignored. Any thoughts?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

If I change my pattern to be just:

```
pattern = r'''
        (?P<name>.+?)\n
        SKU\s#\s+(?P<sku_hidden>\d+)\n
        '''
```

My output comes out like this: `[u'Red Retro Citrus Juicer']` it matches yet the SKU does not appear. If I put everything on the same line, like so:

```
pattern = r'(?P<name>.+?)\nSKU\s#\s+(?P<sku_hidden>\d+)\n'
```

It does match and grab everything.

Comment: Please do include input samples; what should match and what should not? What output do you expect?

Comment: Few comments: **1**. `(?P<gift_wrap>\d+)` will match numbers, not `No` **2**. `Total\sPrice:` won't match `Total:` **3**. Are you sure your newlines are all `\n` and not `\r`? BTW you don't need the multiline flag if you're not using the `^$` anchors.

Comment: Right on 1 and 2, still doesn't work, and I remove all the \r from the text before I apply the regex.

Comment: **1**. After removing the `\r`, you checked that the newline didn't disappear I assume? Also you should edit your question to reflect your changes (previous 1 & 2), it's kind of misleading. **2** It's weird your regex matches but only the first group is captured... How do you try to retrieve them?

Comment: This is how I retrieve them: re.finditer(pattern, plain, re.M | re.X) but using findall yields the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `X` flag, you need to escape the `#`, which start the comments.

Right now your two-line regex is equivalent to

```
(?P<name>.+?)\n
SKU\s
```

What you want is

```
pattern = r'''
    (?P<name>.+?)\n
    SKU\s\#\s+(?P<sku_hidden>\d+)\n
    Quantity:\s+(?P<quantity>\d+)\n
    Gift\sWrap:\s+(?P<gift_wrap>.+?)\n
    Shipping\sMethod:.+?\n
    Price:.+?\n
    Total:\s+(?P<total_price>\$[\d.]+)
    '''
```

Notice the `\#`...

Comment: You the man (y). My job involves using regex every day and I had not run into this for some reason.

Comment: And you beat me to it. I could correct my answer but the downvote wasn't too friendly.

Comment: silly bug :) @MartijnPieters: didn't downvote, I followed the same steps you did.

Comment: It was me, didn't think he was being friendly at all, ironically.